# Adding properties to nested objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I'm trying to create an object that has multiple objects. I then need to add properties to those nested objects.

Here is my code:

```
var collection = {};
_.each(context, function(item, key) {
    collection[key] = {
      'color_id'   : item.Options[0].id || null,
      'color_Name' : item.Options[0].Name || null
    };

  if (item.aOptions[1]) { "you have another set of items!"};

    collection[key] += {
      'price'       : item.Price || null,
      'inStock'     : item.InStock || null,
      'iPk'         : item.id || null
    };        
  }
});
```

FYI, `_.each()` is a [Lodash function](http://lodash.com/docs#forEach).

When I run this, it basically creates two objects nested inside of each `key`'s object. 
Example when `console.log()`ed:

> { num_401510_640070: '[object Object][object Object]' }

My goal is to be able to check for the `if` condition, add it to the object, and then add the remaining portion and have it be a single object. Not multiple objects inside of one object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lodash has a [`_.merge`](http://lodash.com/docs#merge) method.

```
_.merge(object, [source], [callback], [thisArg])
```

So in your case:

```
if (item.aOptions[1]) {
    _.merge(collection[key], {
        'price'       : item.Price || null,
        'inStock'     : item.InStock || null,
        'iPk'         : item.id || null
    });        
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I was unaware of that method. Works perfectly

Comment: @JDillon522: To be honest, I've never used lodash. I just took a quick look through their documentation. Just sayin... ;-)

Comment: Ha. I just got Bazinga'd

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
  if (item.aOptions[1]) { "you have another set of items!"};

    collection[key].price = item.Price || null;
    collection[key].InStock = item.InStock || null;
    collection[key].iPk = item.id || null;  

  }
```

Comment: Blue Skies answer seems more appropriate though if you are already using the lodash library.

Comment: Agreed. Without lodash this would work I believe (I didnt try it)